# Is 'lightning' here a noun or an adjective or even an adverb?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, adverbs, attributive-nouns

[Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lightning) has this example under ADJECTIVE 'lightning':

> (1) *Roman is **lightning** quick and improving every day in practice, and Bean showed playmaking ability in the preseason.*

The adjective is categorized in the dictionary as [ATTRIBUTIVE], which the same dictionary defines as:

> (Of an adjective or other modifier) preceding the word that it modifies and expressing an attribute, as old in the old dog (but not in the dog is old) and expiry in expiry date. Contrasted with predicative.

At first glance, this ***lightning*** in (1) does not seem to be used attributively. For starters, the *quick* clearly is not a noun modified by the *lightning*. Then, is it used predicatively somehow not following the dictionary's own categorization as [ATTRIBUTIVE]?

The only possible way to make that happen is as if the *lightning* were in coordination with the *quick*. But that's unlikely, because without the *quick*, it sounds funky:

> (1a) *Roman is **lightning** and improving every day in practice, and Bean showed playmaking ability in the preseason.* (?)

[Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/lightning) says that lightning in similar cases is an adverb:

> — lightning adverb
>
> — used in combination
>
> (2) *an athlete with lightning-quick reflexes*
>
> (3) *making lightning-fast adjustments*

This just sounds absurd.

And I'm thinking maybe it's just a noun. But I need some feedback on this. Any thoughts?

Comment: Clearly the POS is different in different cases, and many of them don't fit the Classical Eight. There's around a dozen more Parts of Speech that've been discovered since _[DE PARTIBUS ORATIONIS ARS MINOR](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/don.html)* was set in stone (well, almost in stone; "participle" has slipped off the approved list, while "adjective" has snuck in the back way). _Lightning_ is a metaphor for _extremely,_ in a context where speed is being compared. It's also a misspelling for _lightening_, i.e, 'becoming (more) light', in any sense of _light_.

Comment: He's fast. How fast is he? He's as fast as lightning. He's lightning fast. He's red. How red is he? He's as red as an apple. He's apple red.

Comment: It's not just big. It's elephant big!

Answer (score 2):

"lightning" is primarily a noun and you can use it in a formula such as 
"as quick as lightning" or shorter "quick as lightning". In this special case we have an even shorter formula "lightning quick", in which the noun was placed before the adjective quick.
In German we have the same formulas:

schnell wie der Blitz - "quick/fast as the flash" (translation word for word)

blitzschnell - "lightningfast" (written as one word")

As to German it is easy to say something about the word class of blitzschnell.
The whole is a compound adjective with a noun as combining form in the first part.

As to English you get a bit into a jam and I should say it is subject to individual
interpretation.  Furthermore, there are two ways of looking at this composition "lightning quick": You can ask  what kind of word class is the first element and I should say it is a noun. As to the whole composition I think there will be divergent views.
I should say the whole composition acts as a compound adjective with the first element still being a noun as combining form.

(Mari-Lou A will not forgive me that I have drawn attention to a German expression that is parallel to an expression in English. I have tried to abstain from mentioning German, but sometimes the comparative method can make things clearer.)

Comment: I forgive you, but don't make it into a habit :)

Comment: Thanks, Mari-Lou A. - By the way Merriam-Webster Learner's Dictionary spells the compound adjective with a hyphen: lightning-quick.

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you meant. You are right, it must be furthermore. Correction accepted, thanks again.

Comment: Hyphen: Spelling either lightning-quick (wictionary, BrE) or without hyphen.

Comment: I'd opt for the hyphen, it shows the relationship between two words together. *He has lightning-quick reflexes* but *His reflexes were quick as lightning*.

Comment: That's my opinion, too. With a hyphen the composition is much clearer.

Comment: I see what you meant, the "compound adjective" in the question comes only *after* the noun. **Roman is lightning quick and...** (adverb) Whereas in my example lightning-quick (compound adjective) describes his *reflexes*. Wiki says:[Usage in the US and in the UK differs  and often depends on the individual choice of the writer rather than on a hard-and-fast rule; therefore, open, hyphenated, and closed forms may be encountered for the same compound noun...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_compound#Types_of_compound_nouns)

Answer (score 0):

I believe in this case that lightning is a sort of "metaphorical adjective," meaning "quick as lightning."

Comment: "I'm plumb tired" = I have tires like a plumb?

Comment: @Mitch That's a stretch. Tired = tires? plumb = upright.

Comment: @Mitch SrJoven  Yes, but it's a nice stretch!

Comment: Yes, plumb as in straight up. "I am straight up tired." As in justifiably or truly.

Answer (score 0):

[Noun as adjective](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/nouns-adjective.htm) would tend to answer this question.

It's common in English to use a noun as an adjective, especially when categorizing other nouns. One uses documents, and document folders, and document folder cabinets and document folder cabinet storage facilities.

What is the use of lightning in the question? It's a noun used as an adjective.

Comment: If Nouns regularly modify other Nouns, why do we need to say Noun as Adjective when they modify other Nouns :)

Comment: @Araucaria versus what?

Comment: Versus Noun as Noun ...

Comment: @Araucaria When a word is used other than its primary sense, it is convenient to have it be modified to clear up things. 'Horse' is usually considered a noun, but is it a noun in 'horse feathers'. I don't know, it might now be an adjective, it just _looks_ like a noun. Instead of quibbling, just call it a 'noun modifier', a noun that acts like a modifier.

Comment: Wait, that's ambiguous: 'noun modifier' could be a modifier _of_ a noun. Also 'noun' there is itself a noun modifier.

Comment: @Araucaria so you're saying that a noun is always a noun, no matter how it's used, even if it's used to modify other nouns?

Comment: @Mitch, SrJoven, Yes, because it still retains most of the syntactic properties of being a noun. For example, we can try to modify the modifying noun itself, and we will need to use an adjective or other noun, not an adverb: ***animal** enclosure* becomes ***wild animal** enclosure*, not ***wildly animal** enclosure*, that kind of thing.

Comment: @Araucaria I don't believe I tried to assert nouns are adverbs. I can interchange *red* cage with *animal* cage and achieve the same desired effect: red is a word that describes cage (adjective, no argument, right?) and *animal* is a word that describes cage (no argument, right?) but animal is not the subject of the sentence. It is an attribute of cage. But you say "Hold on!" if we put *wild* in front of *animal* it describes animal, not cage! Certainly, and if we add *crimson* in front of *red*, as in crimson red cage, we're intensifying red. But now *crimson red* is now describing the cage.

Comment: @SrJoven I don't believe you did either. My point's just that the noun *animal* is still a noun whether it's modifying *cage* or not. It hasn't become an adjective, even though it's modifying a Noun. We can see this because it takes adjectives not adverbs as modifiers and so forth. If it was an adjective, it would usually be modified by an adverb. If your saying that *animal* in *animal cage* isn't functioning as a subject, I'd agree. It's functioning as a modifier in a Noun Phrase.

Comment: @Araucaria So, you're not disagreeing with my answer at all. Noun being used as adjective is because it's describing another noun. Whether it's "still a noun" or "now an adjective" it's still a noun used in an adjective sense.

Comment: @SrJoven Well kinda. It's just that using that term implies that only adjectives really function as modifiers of nouns and also implies that it's the main job of an adjective to modify a noun (whereas they're used as predicative complements and other complements of verbs etc etc). Setting that aside though, don't you really want to say that *lightning* is being used as an adverb? Because it's modifying an adjective and usually we use adverbs to modify adjectives?

Comment: @Araucaria I don't want to say lightning is used as an adverb. Until this point, you didn't bring that up either. But why take this long to get to that point? See my comment under the OQ? *He's fast. How fast is he? He's as fast as lightning. He's lightning fast. He's red. How red is he? He's as red as an apple. He's apple red.* So, what do you want to say? sure. Adverb, adjective, whatever ... it's a word that describes another word. So *candy apple* red describing an adjective is an adverb ... go for it. I'd rather say intensifier, but whatever.

Comment: I agree with you that it's not an adverb! I just find the *it's an X used as a Y* schema a bit odd (lots of people here use it), so I was wanting to prod it a bit to find out what's up with it and see what the rationale was behind it. :)

Comment: Remember; time flies like an arrow and fruit flys like a banana.

Answer (score 0):

From Google's definition of `adverb`:

> a word or phrase that modifies or qualifies an adjective, verb, or
>   other adverb or a word group, expressing a relation of place, time,
>   circumstance, manner, cause, degree, etc. (e.g., gently, quite, then,
>   there ).

I would call `lightning` an adverb in this case, as it is modifying an adjective.

"Roman is quick."
"How quick?"
"*Lightning* quick."

Answer (score 0):

As @SrJoven suggests in his comment, nouns can be used attributively. Most often they are used as adjectives modifying other nouns

> - car park
> - wedding ring
> - lemon pie

When a noun modifies an adjective, it serves as an adverb

> - apple red
> - lightening quick
> - diamond hard

Comment: Your examples seem to show Nouns used as Nouns modifying other Nouns and then Nouns serving as Nouns modifying Adjectives!

Comment: @Araucaria Nouns can modify nouns or adjectives (or even verb forms). When they are used as such they still nouns, but used *adjectivally* or *adverbially* (or *attributively*).